# Standalone library implementing realloc?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Anyone know a standalone library implementing realloc(), given nothing but a chunk of memory to manage? (The heap.)

I.e. after being initialized with a heap pointer and the size, it provides free/malloc/realloc managing that area.

Comment: you can find a implementation of malloc/free/realloc at ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c, used it a long time ago....

Comment: @pbhd, yes, but that one uses sbrk etc.

Comment: Thats true, but I remember it was quite easy to adopt that implementation to work well in a shared memory segment of fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Allocator examples in "The C Programming Language" book by Kernighan and Ritchie. Also see Doug Lea's malloc/realloc/free implementation (commonly called `dlmalloc`).

The former will give you a simplistic internal view of how the malloc/realloc functions actually work.

The latter will give you a more detailed look into an industry standard implementation of allocator functions.

A `realloc()` implementation of GNU std-c library is not bad either. I hope that answers your question.